# Tensorflow from_generator running out of inputs when fitting

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with images and trying to generate new images based on the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` class in order to augment my dataset. I am having trouble where my generator is running out of examples to generate during the `model.fit`

Here is the function I used to generate the data and create the dataset

```
def tfds_imgen(ds, imgen, batch_size, batches_per):
    for images, labels in ds:
        flow_ = imgen.flow(images, labels, batch_size=batch_size)
        for _ in range(batches_per):
            yield next(flow_)

imgen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=60)

gen = tfds_imgen(
    train_ds.as_numpy_iterator(), imgen,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, batches_per=1)

train_ds_gen = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen,
    output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes = ([None, 64, 64, 3], [None, 120]),
)
```

Here `train_ds` is of shape `(64,64,3)` and I am looking to generate as 1 new image for every image in `train_ds`. Running this code returns the following error: `Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs`.

I understand that the above code only generates 1 epoch worth of images. To fix the issue, I tried increasing the number of images being generated using the `batches_per` argument to be equal to the number of epochs. This fixes the issue, however, when I try to concatenate the `train_ds` with the `train_ds_gen`, I still get a similar issue, since the `train_ds_gen` has 10x more examples than the `train_ds`.

I am looking to get as much generated images as real images in each epoch.

How do I setup my generator to have enough images to be generated while having a dataset that is balanced between generated and real images.

Comment: do you have any specific reasons why you're writing your own function for loading the data since `model.fit()` can directly take in an `ImageDataGenerator` object. Also what do you mean by balancing generated and real images?

Comment: I am looking to concatenate the real images (without transformation) with the augmented data from ImageDataGenerator. The ImageDataGenerator only has the transformed objects
By balanced I mean the same amount of real images as transformed images inside my dataset.